# Is possible to travel within India via Air with an International Driver's License? My Indian Passport renewal application is currently processing

Tags: air-travel, indian-citizens, india, domestic-travel, identity-cards

I want to travel from Lucknow to Bengaluru for a few days while my passport application is being processed. I do not have any other Indian Government issued identification as I have never lived here. I do have a Canadian driver's license & an International Driver's Permit. Will this suffice?

Comment: How are you planning to travel? Plane, train or other?

Comment: If you are travelling with a train, again this link - http://travelonthedollar.com/2012/01/18/carry-proof-of-id-if-traveling-in-ac-class-of-indian-railways/ tells that there is no indication of acceptance of International Drivers Permit or foreign drivers licence as a legitimate proof of ID.

Comment: I plan on travelling via air. I am INDIAN by nationality. I do have my old passport but it has a "Cancelled" stamp on it.  I also have a receipt that shows that I have applied for a new one. It's just I don't have my new passport yet.

I am legally allowed to drive in India if I chose to as the International Driver's Permit allows me. Can it not be considered as a valid ID?

Answer (score 3):

I think yes (for Canadian Driver's Licence rather than just International Driving permit), based on [GoAir](https://www.goair.in/terms-conditions)'s requirements, but would myself choose to check with whichever airline is chosen:

> All Customers must present valid identification at check-in. The valid photo identification documents allowed are:
>
> - Valid Passport / Driving License / Election Voter Card / PAN Card
> - Photo Identity cards issued by Government, Public and reputed Private sector organizations / Photo Credit Card.
>
> In case the Customers do not possess any of the above documents, they
>   should carry a relevant attested document that contains a recent
>   photograph of the traveling Customers.

Clearly here it is photographic identification that is significant.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think the airlines don't really fuss about it as much. It's the airport security guy at the entrance that might cause a problem in my case.

I even have an acknowledgement receipt of the passport application given to me by the PSK when I applied. It has a photo of mine on it as well.

Comment: @pnuts Security at Indian airports requires passengers to have a valid photo identification in addition to the ticket/boarding pass in order to access the departures area (which have check-in desks etc.)

Comment: Well that is his question - Will the security accept International Drivers' permit or Canadian driving license as photo ID for access to the airport?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will be travelling by Air.

India's national carrier, [Air India's document page](http://www.airindia.in/documents-to-carry.htm) states

```
 - Valid travel document for Indian citizens are
 - Valid Passport,
 - PAN card issued by the Income Tax department,
 - Election Photo Identification Card,
 - Valid Driving License,
 - Photo identity card issued by the employer, being government and
   reputed private sector organizations,
 - Photo Credit Card,
 - Children should carry their school identification cards or any other
   photo
 - identification proof,
 - Valid birth certificates of infants,
 - For travel under Concessionary fare types valid relevant IDs.
```

> For Foreign Nationals, the only valid photo ID for travel is Passport.

So you need to have your passport for your travel.

Comment: I plan on travelling via air. I am INDIAN by nationality. I do have my old passport but it has a "Cancelled" stamp on it.  I also have a receipt that shows that I have applied for a new one. It's just I don't have my new passport yet.

I am legally allowed to drive in India if I chose to as the International Driver's Permit allows me. Can it not be considered as a valid ID?

Comment: @Vicky S Why don't you ask that (the driving part) as a separate question? It could be very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

For train travel normally you dont need to have an ID, unless you have an online Ticket.But they can also ask for an ID,
In that case you can politely explain your situation and show some receipt of your Visa processing Center with your Photo ID of Canadian License.
For Air Travel you need one, i think it applies also for Buses.

Comment: I plan on travelling via air. I am INDIAN by nationality. I do have my old passport but it has a "Cancelled" stamp on it.  I also have a receipt that shows that I have applied for a new one. It's just I don't have my new passport yet.

I am legally allowed to drive in India if I chose to as the International Driver's Permit allows me. Can it not be considered as a valid ID?

Comment: I even have an acknowledgement receipt of the passport application given to me by the PSK when I applied. It has a photo of mine on it as well.

Comment: @Unni "securities dont even allow you to enter inside the airport without your passport": does this mean that Indian citizens must get a passport if they want to travel domestically by air?

Comment: @phoog Yes ! you dont need..I found out very lately that OP is Indian by nationality.Foreigner carrying Passport is mandatory to travel inside India.Also if he has a Photo ID card issued by govt of India,then its solved